# Replacing XStream with JAXB in my application

Tags: xml, soap, namespaces, jaxb, xstream

Currently in the application we get a SOAP response xml with namespace attached to each element. I have hard coded into my code that the namespaces are ignored because the application wants clean xml. But  upon testing it is being deemed a weak solution because the namespace might change in the future.
It has been recommended to me to use jaxb. I am using xtream currently because we can directly read xml. So I have started looking into jaxb. But jaxb requires xsd. I have understood the process but I am not sure how to implement Jaxb in my application because I am getting an xml response.
So, my question Is it possible to replace xtream with jaxb in this situation?
thanks

Comment: Also can i use xslt for removing namespaces?

Comment: "but jaxb requires xsd" - incorrect, it requires no such thing.  You may want to do a bit more background reading, your assumptions are a bit off.

Comment: @skaffman Can u elaborate a little more?coz i am new to jaxb and from wat i have seen conversion from xml to java objects  requires  xsd to run the xjc binding compiler.

Comment: You may find the following article helpful.  It maps the same objects to XML using both JAXB and XStream:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the J[**AXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> I am using xtream currently because we can directly read xml. So I
>   have started looking into jaxb. But jaxb requires xsd.

It is a common misconception that JAXB requires an XML schema (it's even on the [XStream FAQ](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Other_Products)).  The truth is that JAXB was designed to start from objects and provides an option to generate annotated object models from an XML schema(s).  This is very useful when dealing with large XML schemas:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

> Currently in the application we get a SOAP response xml with namespace
>   attached to each element. I have hard coded into my code that the
>   namespaces are ignored because the application wants clean xml. But
>   upon testing it is being deemed a weak solution because the namespace
>   might change in the future.

JAXB has very good support for mapping namespaces.  This can be done at the package level with `@XmlSchema`, the class level with `@XmlType`, or the field/property level with `@XmlAttribute`/`@XmlElement`:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

> I have understood the process but I am not sure how to implement Jaxb
>   in my application because I am getting an xml response

Below is a link to an article that maps the same object model to the same XML document using both JAXB and XStream.  It will give you a feel for how some of the concepts relate:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Another thing note is that JAXB refers to a standard (JSR-222) and not a specific implementation.  There are actually several implementations including:

- EclipseLink MOXy
- Metro (the reference implementation)
- Apache JaxMe